# Reading double matrix from cin

Tags: c++, matrix, double, cin

I need to read squad matrix from cin, but I don't know the size of this matrix. So I need to read first row(double numbers separated by space or tab till end of line). After parse this line to get count of double numbers. If in row will be n double numbers then matrix size will nxn. How can I do that?

Code:

```
unsigned int tempSize = 0;
double tempPoint;
double * tempArray = new double [0];
string ts;

getline(std::cin, ts);
std::istringstream s(ts);
while (s >> tempPoint){
    if (!s.good()){
        return 1;
    }
    tempArray = new double [tempSize+1];
    tempArray[tempSize] = tempPoint;
    tempSize++;
}
cout << "temp size " << tempSize << endl;
```

Output:

```
temp size 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and don't worry about the size.

Comment: Problem isn't in place some data somewhere, probles is in read that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read a line using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).
2. Construct a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) from the line.
3. Keep reading numbers from the `std::istringstream` and add them to a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). When you are done reading the contents of the line, the number of items in the `std::vector` gives you the rank of the matrix.
4. Use the same logic that was used to read the first row of the matrix to read the other rows of the matrix.

**EDIT**

```
void readRow(std::vector<int>& row)
{
   std::string ts;
   std::getline(std::cin, ts);
   if ( std::cin )
   {
      std::istringstream s(ts);
      int item;
      while (s >> item){
         row.push_back(item);
      }
   }
   std::cout << "size " << numbers.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I tryed to do that:
getline(std::cin, ts);
    std::istringstream s(ts);
    cout << ts << endl;
    while (s >> tempPoint){
        if (!s.good()){
            return 1;
        }
        tempArray = new double [tempSize+1];
        tempArray[tempSize] = tempPoint;
        tempSize++;
    }
    cout << "temp size " << tempSize << endl;

But I it didn't ask me to print anything, just had end of program and output is:


temp size 0
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Please add that code, with formatting, to your question.

Comment: Done. Some text to add comment

Comment: Works same as my code, but if I used it twise the second one will works good. Maybe I need to clean my cin somehow?

Comment: I read one int number before. When I removed part of code where I'm reading that int, everything works great.