# c++ how to read stream till end of line

Tags: c++, istream

I want to read an input like this from file

> sphere 3 2 3 4
>   pyramid 2 3 4 12 3 5 6 7 3 2 4 1 2 3
>   rectangle 2 3 4 1 9 12

I want to do something like this

```
char name[64];  
int arr[12];  
ifstream file (..);  
while(file)  
{   
file >> name;  
    while( //reach end of line) 
        file >> arr[i]
}
```

As you can see I don't know how many integers will be entered, that's why I want to stop at new line. I did it with getline, and then splitting the line, but they told me it can be done only with >> operator.

Note: I can't use `std::string` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Lookup 'C++ parse CSV' (and have a space as separator)

Comment: @DieterLücking I've been reading for a long time, and couldn't do it. Can you show me?

Comment: *I don't know how many integers will be entered* -- *Note: I can't use std::string or std::vector* -- What if there are more than 12 integers on that line?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know they wont be more than 12

Comment: Why can't you use `getline`?

Comment: Take a look at [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29133486/434551). You can follow a similar strategy.

Comment: I can, and I did it reading each line, then splitting the line and parsing it. But they told me there is an easier way, but I can't find it.

Comment: *I can't use std::string* -- Who comes up with these ridiculous restrictions?  What else can't you use?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie do you really think it's ridiculous to know how to do something without string and vector? Before I start using them, i want to know how it can be done without them ;)

Comment: @Gigata That's like saying you want to solve some complicated integral by substitution when there's already a clear and simpler way to solve via complex contour integration - i.e. use the correct tools for the job.

Comment: *"do you really think it's ridiculous to know how to do something without string and vector?"* Unless you cannot use them, yes. *"Before I start using them, i want to know how it can be done without them"* Waste of time, serious danger of ending up as a *"C with classes"* programmer.

Comment: Recommend using something like `struct thing{ char name[64]; int numbers[12; int numNumbers; };` to keep the name with the numbers. Simplifies the array as well: `thing things[MAX_NUM_THINGS];`

Answer (score 5):

The simple version is to use a manipulator similar to `std::ws` but instead of skipping all whitespace setting `std::ios_base::failbit` when a newline is encountered. This manipulator would then be used to instead of skipping whitespace implicitly whitespace other than newlines are skipped. For example (the code isn't test but I think something like this with the bugs and compilation errors removed should work):

```
std::istream& my_ws(std::istream& in) {
    std::istream::sentry kerberos(in);

    while (isspace(in.peek())) {
        if (in.get() == '\n') {
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return in;
}
// ...
char name[64];
int  array[12];
while (in >> std::setw(sizeof(name)) >> name) {  // see (*) below
    int* it = std::begin(array), end = std::end(array);
    while (it != end && in >> my_ws >> *it) {
        ++it;
    }
    if (it != end && in) { deal_with_the_array_being_full(); }
    else {
        do_something_with_the_data(std::begin(array), it);
        if (!in.eof())  { in.clear(); }
    }
}
```

My personal guess is that the assignment asked for reading the values into `char` arrays followed by converting them using `atoi()` or `strol()`. I think that would be a boring solution to the exercise.

(*) **Never**, not even in exmaple code, use the formatted input operator with a `char` array `array` **without** also setting the maximum allowed size! The size can be set by setting the stream's `width()`, e.g., using the manipulator `std::setw(sizeof(array))`. If the `width()` is `0` when using the formatted input operator with a `char` array, an arbitrary number of non-whitespace characters is read. This can **easily** overflow the array and become a security problem! Essentially, this is the C++ way of spelling C's `gets()` (which is now removed from both the C and the C++ standard libraries).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you can use [peek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/) method:

```
while (file)
{
    file >> name;
    int i = 0;
    while(file.peek() != '\n' && file.peek() != EOF) {
        file >> arr[i++];
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if there are multiple spaces between the values?

Comment: @DietmarKühl Hmm, but what's the problem with multiple spaces?

Comment: The problem is that the newline may be preceded by one and your test for the newline doesn't trigger.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Oh, I see now. I just used OP's input file as a sample without any additional assumptions about spaces in the end of line or something similar...

Comment: I thought of something similar to this, but it doesn't work, and I think it's because under windows new line is marked as `\r\n` :D